# How to properly perform an SVN relocate on Zend for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository, zend-studio

I've been using Zend Studio for Eclipse for about a year, and our SVN repository has gone through a number of different relocations (IP changes, etc.), but I'm never able to correctly move the repository on Zend Studio. What is the standard procedure that you usually follow for such an event?

I assumed I could just go to the SVN repository perspective and change the URL in the properties of the repository, but that didn't work.

I also tried to use the
`svn switch --relocate ....`
command which seemed to corrupt my working copy and I had to go through a lot of pain to get back to square one.

I'm working on MacOSX 10.5.6, Zend Studio for Eclipse 6.1 and SVN on commandline version 1.6.2 (r37639). I'm not sure how to get the version of Subversive (SVN plugin that Zend is using)

I would love one of the geniuses on this site to help out. I've been stuck on this forever. Thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `svn switch --relocate` is indeed the way to do this. With the little information given, it's hard/impossible to tell you what went wrong and how to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

svn switch --relocate is supposed to be used for repointing a working copy at a different IP address. Personally I find when dealing with low-level operations it is better to use the command line svn instead of going through Eclipse. Close Eclipse, run the svn command, then restart Eclipse.

You can always back up your entire working copy by simply making a copy of it before you try something like this.